# Querying with a field stored as Int64 in nodejs mongodb

Tags: node.js, mongodb, int64

I have a collection where a `userID` field is being stored as an Int64. When I use `.find({})` on this collection, the `userID` field is returned as a string. However, when I try to find one specific item in the collection using `.findOne({ userID: req.query.userID }`, I always get no results. I can confirm that the value I'm passing into the query exists in the collection (but it's being passed as a string).

I know that javascript can't handle Int64, but if the field gets returned as a string, is there any way to query it using a string? Or do I have no choice but to modify the field such that it's stored as a string to begin with?

Answer (score 0):

When you do a `findOne()`, use the wrapper for long, like so:

```
.findOne({userID:NumberLong(req.query.userID)})
```

Comment: Thanks, for some reason I never thought to check the docs for other data types... `NumberLong` seems to be shell only though, apparently what's needed is `var Long = require('mongodb').Long; Long.fromString(req.query.userID)`.